# Unable to iterate the CustomerData collection (Invalid Procedure Call error)

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am attempting to store xml metadata within chart shapes in a PowerPoint presentation.

I need to ensure that the shape only contains the current xml data, so I have a function to delete existing data (if any) and add the current data.

```
Sub Test()
Dim cht as Chart
Dim xml as String
Set cht = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
xml = "<Chart property1='true' property2='false'>blah blah blah</Chart>"

    EmbedChartXML xml, cht

End Sub

Sub EmbedChartXML(xml As String, cht As Shape)
Dim x As Variant

    'Get rid of any previous data
    For Each x In cht.CustomerData
        x.Delete
    Next

    Set xmlPart = cht.CustomerData.Add

    xmlPart.LoadXML xml
End Sub
```

The `For Each` loop is failing with the indicated error message.  I can see that the `cht.CustomerData.Count = 2` (for example), but if I try to view this in the Locals window, I get the same error.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here is another test routine that is failing, even though there is nothing inside the For/Next loop.

```
Sub TestIteration()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim pres As Presentation
Dim shp As Shape
Dim x As CustomXMLPart

Set pres = ActivePresentation
Set sld = pres.Slides(2)

For Each shp In sld.Shapes

    Set pptCustomerData = shp.CustomerData

    For Each x In shp.CustomerData

'    For Each pptCustomXMLPart In pptCustomerData
'        Debug.Print pptCustomXMLPart.Id
'    Next
    Next
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: can't reproduce your error, what do you examine in locals, `cht`? Btw, shouldn't you use `Dim cht as Shape` instead `Dim cht as Chart`?

Comment: I'm trying to examine the `cht.CustomerData` and it will not "expand" in the locals view, although a `.Count` indicates there are 2 (or more).  Perhaps yes on the `Dim`, I only put that in for ease of someone else testing it, that is not actually the code I use but I will double-check the type of my variables doesn't affect it...

Comment: about `.Count=2` in your screen you have `Debug.Pring x.Id`, but in test code `x.Delete`..Is there an issue? I can expand `cht.CustomerData` without any problem (ppt 2013):  http://i.stack.imgur.com/xSm5d.png

Comment: It doesn't matter what I put inside the loop -- even if I put nothing inside the loop, it's like the iteration itself is failing.  I can expand it now, and I see a `.Count` = 13, then if I close and re-expand it, the error happens...

Comment: does this error occurs only in particular ppt file or if you create new presentation and run your code (from this post) it also errors?

Comment: I don't have any other files that have any Custom XML data in the shapes/slides. This is first attempt...

Comment: can you share you presentation to work with? Aslo try to `SaveAs` your presentation and run code on copy

Comment: Yeah I've created a new presentation it's still not working.  The file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1v0s8ldwHRYSHZxMU5jWUdFb1k/edit?usp=sharing).  You can copy that code  in to  anew file and I htink it wil work the **first** time, but not subsequent attempts.

Comment: I've run code many times, but still can't reproduce your error..can you run your presentation on any other PC?

Comment: I'm at home now so unable to test on any other machines until monday. I suppose I can use the shapes `.AlternativeText` property if needed, but would prefer to use the Customer Data if I can figure out what's wrong...

Comment: When I do `x.Delete`, the peculiar thing is that `x` still appears in the Locals window with all its properties intact, and the `.Count` increases by 1 each time. But I'm forever unable to iterate that collection or delete the items...

Comment: @simoco FYI another user replicates my error, both using PPT 2010.  I have found another method that appears to be working, and posted as answer, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others here cannot replicate this error in Excel 2013 (I am using Excel 2010) where the collection object itself becomes inaccessible. Perhaps there is a bug or something, but I could not find much on Google about similar errors...

I ultimately arrive at this solution.  I am not sure why the CustomXMLPart's `.Delete` method doesn't actually *delete* the item from the collection (instead it makes it to `Nothing`, and then failure on successive iteration attempts).

Instead, I use the `CustomerData.Delete` method. This seems to be working as expected.

```
Sub EmbedChartXML(xml As String, cht As Shape)
Dim x As Variant
Dim cData As CustomerData

Dim xID As String

    Set cData = cht.CustomerData
    Debug.Print cht.CustomerData.Count

    'Get rid of any previous data
    For Each x In cData
        xID = x.Id
        cData.Delete xID
    Next

    With cData.Add
        .LoadXML xml
    End With

    Debug.Print cht.CustomerData.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: I hate to jump to that conclusion but it does seem like that. I'm surprised there seems to be very little about this anywhere on the web. I knwo it's a little-used feature, but still figured someone would have run in to it before...